# How to select a specific list item from an unordered list in Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select a specific list item using Selenium Web driver from an UL, but when the test runs it doesn't find locate the Element.

My Selenium Code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("postcode-field")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("postcode-field")).sendKeys("GL32BN");
driver.findElement(By.id("postcode-field")).submit();
driver.findElement(By.id("5000955")).click();
```

The related HTML:

```
<ul class="address-list">
<li data-uprn="" data-premise-id="5127035" data-site-id="05">
            1 Pelham Crescent, Gloucester, GL3 2BN
        </li>
<li data-uprn="" data-premise-id="5000955" data-site-id="05">
            2 Pelham Crescent, Gloucester, GL3 2BN
        </li>
```

Comment: I don't see in the HTML you posted where the elements are with id "postcode-field" or "5000955". For the second one, I think you are mistaking id for `data-premise-id`. If you change the locator to `By.cssSelector("li[data-premise-id='5000955']");`, that should work.

Comment: I tried this and it still seems to not recognise the element in the list. So should I be locating the whole list before selecting the individual element? This is the URL with the list. You need to input the post code first. www.virginmedia.com/shop/bundles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked fine for me. I'm not sure if you tried a wait or not.

```
// enter the postcode into the field
driver.findElement(By.id("postcode-field")).sendKeys("GL32BN");
// click the magnifying glass icon to initiate the search
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[data-text-original='Submit']")).click();
// wait for the desired element to be clickable (it takes a fraction of a second to open the dropdown and populate it)
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("li[data-premise-id='5127035']")))
        .click();
// click the next button
driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Could you explain the principal behind this: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[data-text-original='Submit']")).click();  

is this a way of  navigating to the whole list before identifying the individual list element?

Also, how did you know to include he wait?

Comment: I've added comments to each line of code. Let me know if that doesn't answer your question. I didn't know to include the wait until it didn't work without it... :). I generally assume no waits are needed and don't add them. Experience has taught me some times when waits are needed. I generally don't add one until the non-wait code fails because an element can't be found, etc. I investigate and add a wait if I think it will fix the issue and run it again. Much of automation is trial and error. Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
5000955 is not the id attribute's value which you have used in your code. 5000955 is the value of 'data-premise-id' attribute.
you can use driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[data-premise-id='5000955']")).click(); instead of driver.findElement(By.id("5000955")).click();

To select list item, first of all You have to click on an element, from where list is display, then, click on list item.

and make sure that data-premise-id attribute's value should be static.
```

Comment: I tried this and it still seems to not recognise the element in the list. So should I be locating the whole list before selecting the individual element? This is the URL with the list. You need to input the post code first. http://www.virginmedia.com/shop/bundles.html